# Perl6 Rakudo Star: Why does it take so long to install?

Tags: raku, rakudo, rakudo-star

I'm not trying to hate on Perl 6, but I'm wondering why the installation takes so long, in comparison to say Common Lisp.  Thanks in advance.

-comborico1611 20th of April, 2018

Edit: On my laptop purchased 3 years ago, it takes about 25-30 minutes. In comparison, Common Lisp, via Portacle, takes like a few minutes if even that.

Update: 23 April 2018

I've been asked to clarify my question -- regarding whether I want to know how to speed up the installation.  The nature of my question is "why" not "how" -- a question of curiosity, not application.

I believe this has been answer by Azsgy, but I'm not certain.  I was unaware of installations being either built from scratch or "finished-build".  This probably is the reason why it is slow.

Comment: you're probably compiling perl from scatch, while you are using finished builds for common lisp.

Comment: Do you include running the full spec test suite and tests for all modules in your installation timing?

Comment: Heh, no. I skipped the testing.  I did the testing once before, and it took FOREVER!  (an hour or more)

Comment: Please clarify a bit your question. Do you want tips on faster installation procedures, tips for speeding it up in its current form?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't really on topic for Stack Overflow. That said, Perl 6 is a vastly larger than most other languages.

Comment: If compilation time is an issue, just install a pre-built rakudo. https://rakudo.org/files has lots of options. Another one that should work pretty much everywhere these days is the Docker image, https://hub.docker.com/_/rakudo-star/

Answer (score 3):

In the case you run Linux, I provide native packages and repos here:
https://nxadm.github.io/rakudo-pkg/ (also linked from the Perl6 and Rakudo homepages).

At the moment you'll find Alpine, CentOS, Debian, Fedora, openSUSE and Ubuntu packages.

Comment: Great! If I already have a working previous version of Perl 6, should I uninstall it before adding your source and installing from it?

Comment: rakudo-pkg is self-contained: it installs everything on /opt/rakudo-pkg. You'll need to update your PATH to point to the perl6 binary you want to use. Once using the packages (or better: the repos), you can update as with regular packages.

Comment: The idea of rakudo-pkg is not not conflict with other rakudo installations, e.g. rakudo installed by the distribution (e.g. /usr/bin/perl6) or Rakudo Star.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Since it has a very fast stable release cycle (every month) and a fast "star" release cycle (every three months), in Linux it is advised that it is [installed from source](https://rakudo.org/files/star/source). This means that it is compiled from scratch in your particular system, and that is done in two phases: first the [MoarVM](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM) virtual machine is compiled, and then the Rakudo compiler is compiled to code that is interpreted on that virtual machine from its [Not Quite Perl](https://github.com/perl6/nqp) (which is compiled first) and Perl 6 sources.

That takes a while, but the result is an efficient virtual machine, built to order, with all the latest bells and whistles and bug fixes installed.

If you don't want to wait, there are many other options, from binaries created for different distros, to Docker containers.

Comment: Every monthly release is a stable release. If there is something blocking, the release will be postponed. The 3 monthly release is just Rakudo Star's (as it needs more time to stabilize the modules that are part of the distribution). (I know you know, @jjmerelo, just to clarify).

Comment: @nxadm changed that. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: A long time is also spent on testing and installing all the additional modules via zef. This usually takes longer for me than the compilation of the other parts.